# change from hardcoded user to mySQL users Spring login

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

SecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().

                authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//      auth.userDetailsService(userService);
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("javainuse@yahoo.com").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");
    }   

}
```

my entity class

```
@Entity
public class Manager {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Timestamp registration_date;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "manager")
    private Image image;
```

ManagerController class

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;   
import com.stankovic.model.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/managers")
public class ManagerController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    @RequestMapping({ "/validateLogin" })
    public User validateLogin() {
        return new User("User successfully authenticated");
    }       
}
```

So it is working fine, just it is hard coded. User wants to use use database users to login. I am connecting with Angular.  If somebody can help I got confused. So I use MySQL or PosgreSQL - I have drivers already and data source set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create table

```
CREATE TABLE t_account (
  name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  enabled TINYINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

Code in spring security:

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

   auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}
```